# Conditional rendering reactjs

Tags: reactjs, conditional-formatting

Please I am trying to use conditional rendering but I can't seem to get it right. I want to conditionally display the product and page. Such that on the click of `<button>Cart{this.state.count}</button>` it takes user to the cart page

```
 render() {
      return (
       <div>
          <div id="container">
      <button>Cart {this.state.count}</button>
          {this.state.products.map((product) =>(
            <div key={product.id} id="products">
            <img className="img" src={product.image} alt=""/>
            <h1>{product.category}</h1>
            <h4>{product.price}</h4>
            <button onClick={() => this.addCart(product)}>Add to Cart</button>
                  </div>))}
         </div>
          
                <div className="cart">
                  {this.state.cart?.map((item) => (
                    <div className="itemBox">
                      <div>
                        <img className="cartImage" src={item.image} />
                      </div>
                      <button onClick={()=>this.removeCart(item)}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
       )

}
}
export default App
```

Comment: Which routing library are you using?  The docs for it should tell you how to do this.

Comment: Non. i want manage routing via state

Answer (score 0):

`<button onClick={onHandleClick}>Cart {this.state.count}</button>`

```
const onHandleClick=()=>{
   this.props.history.push('/cartPage');  // push your cart page component, needs to define in routes
}
```

refer this - https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start